# How do you cache a route with a wildcard in a PWA service worker?

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to convert my application to a PWA and I understand that I need to provide a complete list of endpoints and static files to the service worker, so it can manage the caching. In all the examples I'm finding, the pages are static links like `/report`. But in most real world applications, the pages contain dynamic parts, like `/report/{reportId:int}`. How do you tell the service worker about such an endpoint?

Comment: Are you using a library like Workbox, or just writing your own "vanilla" service worker by hand?

Comment: I've been looking at Workbox, but it's not a great fit for my toolchain and I'd also like to try it by hand, at least at first, so I can understand what's going on, and not rely on a third party black box for something so important to the way my application works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript test() method and check if the url matches the regExp expression that would fit your url.

You can read about it on this official guide:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook#putting_it_together

extract:

```js
if (/^\/article\//.test(requestURL.pathname)) {
    event.respondWith(/* some other combination of patterns */);
    return;
}
```

Comment: You could combine this approach with, e.g., https://github.com/lukeed/regexparam to consume "Express-style" routes and turn them into RegExps.